# Firing Android Activity methods on separate process at set interval

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am writing my first Android app(allot of fun so far!) and have run into a roadblock. I am using SDK tools 21.1 targeting Android 4.2.

I am trying to set up a system that allows activities to register to invoke a method at set time intervals. I wanted to do this in such a way that the processing of the request would be handled on it's own process to avoid making the UI unresponsive.

I have been doing some reading and have explored a few avenues. First I thought that  a service would be a good way to go about this but found a fair bit of information suggesting that was not a good course of action due to the OS being able to kill services indiscriminately.

I'm now looking at using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. I've created this simple class with an overridable method to pass methods around:

```
public abstract class BaseEvent implements EventListener {

    public abstract void onFire(Object... params);
}
```

I've created this runnable task invoke the method:

```
public class HeartBeatTask implements Runnable {


    private BaseEvent mCallback;

    private Object mParams;

    public HeartBeatTask(BaseAioEvent callback,Object... params){
        mParams = params;

        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Run called");
        if(mCallback != null)
        {
            mCallback.onEvent(mParams);
        }

    }
}
```

I'm going to use it like this (inside an Activity)

```
      ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
      BaseEvent callback = new BaseEvent() {
            public void onFire(Object... params){
                if(params[0] !=null)
                {
                    Context context = (Context)params[0];
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Task ran", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }

      };

      threadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HeartBeatTask(callback,(this)),0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will execute the task every 5 seconds, although the callback method is only being run once.

I'm thinking that this may not be a good way to do things. My feeling is that I'm overcomplicating things. What I really need is the ability to have something that will execute a method, on a process other than the main thread, and at a set interval, that activities can bind multiple actions to. So, for instance, I may want to have a UI component update after a call is made to a database, and would want that to happen every minute.

Could any tell me if I am on the right track here? Is what I am trying to do a viable way to accomplish my goal? Is there a better approach I could be taking? Any advice or suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a few suggestions for an Android beginner.

- Don't call it a `separate process`. [Process is a different thing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=linux%20process&aq=f&oq=linux%20process&aqs=chrome.0.59j60j0l3j62.1449&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (Google 'Linux process'), you want to call them on a separate thread inside the same process.
- `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` **IS** better than anything else people will suggest you here such as Timers or PostDelayed.

But I think you do have a philosophical error here as to UI updates shouldn't be running on a timed manner but on an event base instead. Once your Db, Disk or Network operation finishes from a background thread you callback to the UI thread to update it immediately.

There`re several tools for that and I'll list a few, point the one I like the best, but let you do some research on each one

- [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29): That's basic java way
- [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html): Nice framework but doesn't handle screen rotation
- [Loader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html): That's my preferred way

Answer (score 1):

Android is a mobile platform and in all honesty each time you want something run, you better consider it separately. You may be killing the battery or using resources for no reason. I begrudge Zedge app everyday for running for no reason in the background at all times. Especially since on CyanogenMod kernel puts WiFi to sleep, while apparently it is currently on.

I am guessing this is more of an exercise and for running tasks at a specified intervals. One-offs, most universal can be done via AlarmManager class. But this may not be the best solution.

For some system wide events there is the BroadcastReceiver class.

While addressing

> So, for instance, I may want to have a UI component update after a call is made to a database, and would want that to happen every minute.

Easier done via an Interface really.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is a bit complicated. Consider you example

```
So, for instance, I may want to have a UI component update after a call is made
to a database, and would want that to happen every minute.
```

I think I will do it this way.

1. Create a AsyncTask which will update the UI component.
2. Create a thread which will execute a new AsyncTask and sleep one minute in a while loop.
3. Start the thread in step 3. at some point.
4. Interrupt the thread if you don't want the component to be updated.

Example of step 2

```
while (true) {
    try {
        new updateTask.execute();
        Thread.sleep(60000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```